# Select Freeform email recipients from dropdown (not dynamic recipients field)

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I have a Freeform form where the user selects their area of interest from a dropdown. I need the email to be sent to different email addresses, based on the area of interest (some will have multiple addresses).

I thought I could do it with the dynamic recipients field, but that doesn't let me customize the label (it needs to be the area of interest, not the email address).

I tried setting the values of a regular dropdown field as the email address, with the areas of interest as the label, and then setting setting the admin recipients of the email to [[ interestedIn }} (the dropdown field name), and I can submit the form, but the email is not sent.

Is there another way to accomplish this?